# Why does my model not bind properly when using pre-rendering?

Tags: javascript, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.1

My Angular app element looks like this, in the `Home/Index/` view:

```
<app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>

<script src="~/dist/vendor.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
@section scripts {
    <script src="~/dist/main-client.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
}
```

When I run the app as is, I get an error page before my application renders anything. The error on that page is:

> Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: Template
>   parse errors: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property
>   of 'input'. ("/label>  ][(ngModel)]="user.FirstName" class="form-control" />

There is one such error for every `[(ngModel)]="*model.propName*"`binding on the only Angular component I have introduced, the `Register` page.

If I remove the `asp-prerender-module` from the `app` tag, it doesn't render at all, but just shows the text "Loading...".

Comment: Have you added the `FormsModule` to your `AppModule`?

Comment: @PierreDuc Yes, it's automatically added as part of the `dotnet new angular`template.